How to Reactivate the Last Focused Window After My Qt App Closes on macOS
I'm developing a screenshot-taker application using Qt and need some assistance with macOS-specific behavior.
Here’s the scenario:

When I take a screenshot, my application becomes focused to allow the user to draw over the screenshot.
After editing, the user can copy the edited screenshot.
The problem is that the previously focused window (for example, a Chrome window) loses focus and remains unfocused even after my application closes.

What I want to achieve:

Programmatically refocus the last focused window that was active before my application became active.

Is there any way to achieve this using macOS APIs? Specifically, I’m looking for a method to track and reactivate the previously focused window from my application. Any guidance, suggestions, or code snippets would be greatly appreciated!
